# Marketing Cloud SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to write a custom web service and using following code snippet from [Fuel SDK documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/data-extension-column-retrieve.htm)

```
Using FuelSDK;  
ET_Client myclient = new ET_Client();  
ET_DataExtensionColumn dataextensioncolumn = new ET_DataExtensionColumn();  
dataextensioncolumn.AuthStub = myclient;  
PostReturn response = dataextensioncolumn.Post();  
Console.WriteLine("Post Status: " + response.Status.ToString());
```

However, I am getting error at this line of code at Post menthod call

```
PostReturn response = dataextensioncolumn.Post();
```

**Error: C# does not contain a definition for and no extension method accepting a first argument of type could be found**

Note- I am using Fuel SDK and same is added to my project in C#

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

`ET_DataExtensionColumn` class does not have a Post method. You should call that method in `ETDataExtension` with the row properly configured.

You can take a look here: [`ETDataExtension`](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp/blob/master/FuelSDK-CSharp/ETDataExtension.cs)

```
public class ETDataExtension : DataExtension
{
    internal string FolderMediaType = "dataextension";

    public int? FolderID { get; set; }

    public ETDataExtensionColumn[] Columns { get; set; }

    public PostReturn Post()
    {
        ETDataExtension de = this;
        de.Fields = Columns;
        de.Columns = null;
        var pr = new PostReturn(de);
        foreach (var rd in pr.Results)
        {
            ((ETDataExtension)rd.Object).Columns = (ETDataExtensionColumn[])((ETDataExtension)rd.Object).Fields;
            ((ETDataExtension)rd.Object).Fields = null;
        }
        return pr;
    }

    public PatchReturn Patch()
    {
        ETDataExtension de = this;
        de.Fields = Columns;
        de.Columns = null;
        var pr = new PatchReturn(de);
        foreach (var rd in pr.Results)
        {
            ((ETDataExtension)rd.Object).Columns = (ETDataExtensionColumn[])((ETDataExtension)rd.Object).Fields;
            ((ETDataExtension)rd.Object).Fields = null;
        }
        return pr;
    }

    public DeleteReturn Delete()
    {
        ETDataExtension de = this;
        de.Fields = Columns;
        return new DeleteReturn(de);
    }

    public GetReturn Get()
    {
        var r = new GetReturn(this);
        LastRequestID = r.RequestID;
        foreach (ETDataExtension rd in r.Results)
        {
            rd.Columns = (ETDataExtensionColumn[])rd.Fields;
            rd.Fields = null;
        }
        return r;
    }

    public GetReturn GetMoreResults()
    {
        var r = new GetReturn(this, true, null);
        LastRequestID = r.RequestID;
        foreach (ETDataExtension rd in r.Results)
        {
            rd.Columns = (ETDataExtensionColumn[])rd.Fields;
            rd.Fields = null;
        }
        return r;
    }

    public InfoReturn Info() { return new InfoReturn(this); }
}
```